# How to get all Signalr core hubs and their mapped URLs?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, signalr-hub, signalrcore

In ASP.NET Core MVC, we can use `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` to get a list of all action methods and razor pages along with their routing path.

How can I get all the SignalR hubs along with their routing path, finally having a dictionary like `Dictionary<HubType, HubPath>`